# Why my stub Sinon.Stub is ignored?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm wondering why my stub is ignored.

Let say I have a file called `myfile.ts` which exports two async methods. `A`  and `B`.

```js
import { sendResult } from '../index'

export async A(): Promise<string[]> {
  // making an async api call
  const result = await apiCall()
  // do sync treatement on result then send it back
  ...
  return value
}

export async B(): Promise<void> {
  // Calling A()
  const aResult = await A()
  // do some sync treatement and call a method from an other module than 
  // returns a Promise<void>
  ...
  sendResult()
}
```

I need to unit test my `B` method and stub `A` and `sendResult`

My testFile.ts looks like

```js
import { sandbox } from 'sinon'
import * as AB from './modules/ab'
import * as INDX from './index'

const testSandbox = sandbox.create()

describe('my tests', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    testSandbox.stub(INDX, 'sendResult').resolves()
    testSandbox.stub(AB, 'A').resolves([])
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    testSandbox.restore()
  })

  it('should pass but it is not', async function (done) {
    await AB.B()
    const sendResultStub = UL.sendResult as SinonStub
    assert.calledOnce(sendResultStub)
    done()
  })
})
```

I do not understand why `sendResult` is well stubed but `A` is not. What do I miss?

Thanks is advances folks!

Bastien